# use xpath or css selector to parse all the element in a hybrid mobile app

Tags: css, xpath, css-selectors, appium

I am currently working for a mobile UI automation testing. Our application is hybrid mobile app based on Cordova. So I am planning to use appium to run some automation tests.

One thing I need to figure out is how to find all the element in a page.

I was previously planed to use xpath to find all elements, since we can detect xpath through appium inspector. However, my colleague does not agree with me, since he wants to use css selectors as the key to find all element in the mobile app. But for appium, it does not show css selector in the inspector.

So, i am just curious which approach should be better?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is my breakdown of Locators and how/why I like to use each for iOS Automation. All of this is experiential based on my work with Native iOS applications.

**Giant disclaimer:** 
I don't know anything about Cordova. I hear there are issues that exist with UIAutomation if there are class names that aren't native. If that is the case, I suggest sticking to accessibility id and class name locator strategy.

## Locators for iOS Automation

### CSS Selectors

CSS Selectors do not exist in Appium.

### Class Name

The closest you'd get to CSS Selectors is the Class Name selector. I don't really use them because UIAutomation gives me what I need and allows me to check for the name/text of the element in the locator strategy.

### XPath

You don't want to use XPath because it's slow and flakey on iOS. (It can sometimes return an entirely incorrect element). It can sometimes cause Instruments to fail for no reason. Highly suggest staying away from XPath.

### Accessibility ID

You should use this when UIAutomation fails to find the element. It's quicker than XPath but is useful when UIAutomation doesn't let you at an element (`.actionSheets()` is broken I think. I use this for when the action sheet is up and I need to `.click()` a button)

### UIAutomation

**You should use Apple's [UIAutomation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/instrumentsuserguide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html), [2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html) framework as it is the quickest, native solution to iOS.**

The UIAutomation framework allows you to use classes and hierarchy to specify which element you want. When you use Appium, use the `find_elements_by_ios_uiautomation` function on your webdriver.

**Example Usage** [here](https://github.com/appium/python-client#finding-elements-by-ios-uiautomation-search)

But the example usage doesn't tell you how powerful UIAutomation really is. A common problem I ran into is trying to find all cells of a tableview when there was more than one tableview on the screen.

#### Find all UIACells for the UIATableview "Cart"

```
**Sample View Hierarchy** 

  <application>
    <window>
        <table name="Items">
          <cell name="Foo, not in cart"></cell>
        </table>
        <table name="Cart">
          <cell name="Bar. IM IN YOUR CART"></cell>
        </table>
    </window>
  </application>
```

OK now to find those cells in an array:

```
value = '.tableviews()["Cart"].cells()'
cells = driver.find_elements_by_ios_uiautomation(value)
```

**Extra Reading:** [Guide](http://www.mattmccomb.com/blog/2013/06/02/ios-functional-testing-with-uiautomation/) that goes over predicates and why they're awesome

#### Limitations for UIAutomation

1. If your element doesn't have a visible name. (Developers like to put invisible buttons behind "Hint Overlays" and the like.)

   - **Suggested Solution:** add an accessibility id, use the accessibility id locator.

## Testing locator strategies

There's a nice place in the Inspector (provided in the Appium.app GUI) which lets you try whatever locator strategy and value you want. You should use it. It helps so, so much.

[image: Testing Locators with Appium.app Inspector]

Comment: wow, it really helps. Your answer is great. I will dig around in UIAutomation, to start the automation testing. But there is one thing that i need to mention is that the automation test is not just for IOS, but also for Android.... So I am not sure whether I need to write two different parse for the app.

Comment: Make sure to upvote me in addition to accepting the answer :P

Comment: Also email me if you want some suggestions as to how to handle diff locators for Android + iOS. I'm really happy with the way I solved it. jess@myusername.com